# How is thesis evaluated in pure mathematics for PhD?

Tags: phd, mathematics, thesis, thesis-committee

I am a Ph.D. student in pure mathematics with a few published works in my field. I would like to know how Ph.D. students are evaluated by the examiners before the defense. What are essential points to be careful about when writing a thesis? I would also like to know how much time is usually taken from submission to defense.

Comment: Have you asked your adviser these questions?

Comment: What country are you studying in?

Comment: @AnonymousM Yes I have asked him but still, I would like to know from other people's perspectives.

Comment: @Buffy I am studying in India

Comment: It will range from "read all proofs closely" to "do not even open."

Comment: Also, possibly significantly, by "with few published works", do you mean "_A_ few published works..."? In contemporary U.S. English that would mean that you have 3 or 5 papers, or more. To say you have "few published papers" (without the article "a") would mean that you have perhaps just 2, or 1, or none. Yes, this is a volatile aspect of contemporary U.S. English... but/and can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett I did not know the difference. Thank you. I have 2 accepted and 3 published research papers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if this is applicable to India, but, since you want a general answer, I can say a few things.

Generally, at least in the US, the expectation is that the thesis is publishable work. In other words it makes a *significant* and *novel* contribution to mathematical knowledge. You don't have to solve a famous unsolved problem, but you need to make a definite contribution.

Your thesis needs to show that you have some deep insight into a narrow part of mathematics and that you have the capability to do more, perhaps in collaboration with others.

It should also demonstrate that you can write and express things clearly and correctly.

However, your thesis can be your first significant work, not the most important work of your career, assuming you stay in academia. So, the Riemann Hypothesis is out.

---

I have no idea about timing. Your committee will need time to do a review, hopefully more complete than a cursory reading. Most of my committee (long long ago) couldn't understand everything in my dissertation, as they were from different specialties, but they could sort of grasp its importance. The latter was partly due to the assurance given by my advisor to them, as he was well respected.

Comment: "However, your thesis should be your first work" is simply wrong (but true for most students).

Comment: How about "can be your first significant work", then, @MoisheKohan. That was my intent.

Comment: Much better.....

Comment: @MoisheKohan, my "first work" was more than 60 years ago in secondary school. It was published (part of a book) only recently. It won an award back then, but wouldn't have been publishable as a stand-alone (then or now). But it was "insight revealing" and so has pedagogical value for those learning math.

Comment: Examples I had in mind were Milnor's paper "On the total curvature of knots" (not a part of his thesis, 121 citations on MathSciNet), or John Pardon's undergraduate work, or Drinfeld's HS work...

Comment: ... yes, let's not be tooooo pedantic in use-of-words here... :)